# How can I reload dhclient without restarting network?

Tags: 14.04, restart, dhclient, cloud-init

I am using ubuntu 14.04 on ec2 instance, I am changing dhcp settings as part of the provisioning process, and I cant find a way to reload the dhclient. Infact, theres no way to restart network on 14.04 cloud instances. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13):

The -r flag explicitly releases the current lease, and once the lease has been released, the client exits. Open a terminal and type the command:

```
$ sudo dhclient -r
```

Now obtain fresh IP:

```
$ sudo dhclient
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct; it doesn't reload the service. I'm in the same situation - needing to change options in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`, then restarting the service. When `dhclient -r` is run without any options, it can't even locate the proper PID file, as dhclient is configured per interface.

Comment: @oasisbob I got an error message running `sudo dhclient` after `sudo dhclient -r`, however it did correctly reload the file for me.

Comment: As @oasisbob says. Never invoke another instance of dhclient. You will have two processes running on the same interface.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I do this by running `dhclient` as a single command like so:

```
$ sudo -Es
$ dhclient -r; dhclient
```

You can use this trick if you've made changes to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
timeout 300;
retry 60;
supersede domain-search "dom1.mydom.com", "dom2.mydom.com";
prepend domain-name-servers 192.168.7.185,192.168.7.186;
```

#### References

- [Linux Force DHCP Client (dhclient) to Renew IP Address](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-renew-dhcp-client-ip-address/)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah... no. dhclient -x or dhclient -r didn't work for me.
What did work was

```
sudo su
ps fax
```

then copy the *entire* command-line that starts with `/sbin/dhclient`, including all the command-line options, file paths, etc...
Then

```
pkill dhclient
```

and paste the command-line from `ps fax` into your terminal and hit enter.